# using same props of caller component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The goal of my code is to make the `properties` in `InputGroup.js` available to `this.props` in the lowest-level components `TextInput.js, Checkbox.js`, and so on.

To do this, I create a very simple component called `InputComponent.js`, and what I do here is to create `this.prpt` and assign `this.props` to it so that it can be used instead of `this.props` in `TextInput.js`.

I seem to be verbose and I think there is a better way, but I wonder if there is a better way to do this.

In a nut shell, I want to use `this.props`, `on TextInput.js` not like  `this.props.properties` or `this.props.data`.

---

## InputGroup.js

`InputGroup.js` works on the component corresponding to the incoming input_type value.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {INPUT_TYPES as T} from './constants';
import {TextInput, CheckboxInput, SelectInput, MobileInput, DateInput, SnsAuthInput} from '.';

class InputGroup extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        let input_type = this.props.type;
        let switcher = {
            [T.TEXT]: TextInput,
            [T.CHECKBOX]: CheckboxInput,
            [T.SELECT]: SelectInput,
            [T.MOBILE]: MobileInput,
            [T.DATE]: DateInput,
            [T.SNSAUTH]: SnsAuthInput
        }
        let TagName = (input_type < Object.keys(switcher).length) ? switcher[(input_type)] : undefined;
        if (TagName) {
            return <TagName properties={this.props} />
        }
        return <div></div>
    }
}
```

## InputComponent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class InputComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.prpt = this.props.properties;
    }
}

export default InputComponent ;
```

## TextInput.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import InputComponent from './InputComponent';

class TextInput extends InputComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        let {input_id, text, isRequired, error} = this.prpt;
        return (
            <div className="input-group input-text">
                <label htmlFor={input_id} className="blind">{text}</label>
                <input type="text" id={input_id} placeholder={text} required={isRequired}/>
                <span className="id-error">{error}</span>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default TextInput ;
```

---

[EDIT]
I think my question title does not describe the point so that I corrected it.

---

[EDIT]
Now I understood about this so I correct the title and add well known solution.

```

## InputGroup.js - Edit

```
class InputGroup extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        let input_type = this.props.type;
        let switcher = {
            [T.TEXT]: TextInput,
            [T.CHECKBOX]: CheckboxInput,
            [T.SELECT]: SelectInput,
            [T.MOBILE]: MobileInput,
            [T.DATE]: DateInput,
            [T.SNSAUTH]: SnsAuthInput
        }
        let TagName = (input_type < Object.keys(switcher).length) ? switcher[(input_type)] : undefined;
        if (TagName) {
            return <TagName {...this.props} />
        }
        return <div></div>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this.

```
<Parent propX={x} propY={y} />
  <Child {...props} />
```